# How to add multiple instances of class in an array loop?

Tags: java

Main class is Zoo, Animal class performs Polymorphism by calling the pinStick method from each different Animal (other classes)

In the zoo array loop, int r's value is decided by Math.random which is 1 or 0 each time, resulting in a squeak, or a roar, depending which animal class is called.

My question is, how can I include an instance of the class Monkey to be printed every time the Mouse or Lion is called (in the if statement)

The aim is add a new instance of the monkey class so that in the result printout you have “OoOoAhAh” together with “Squeak” and “Roar”

```
public class Zoo {

private Animal[] animals;

public Zoo() {
    animals = new Animal[10];
}

public void talkAnimals() {
    int r;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        r = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
        if (r == 0) {
            animals[i] = new Mouse();


        } else{
            animals[i] = new Lion();

        }

       }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        animals[i].pinStick();

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    new Zoo().talkAnimals();
}
```

}

```
public class Animal {

protected String name;

public Animal(){
}

public void pinStick(){

}
```

}

```
public class Mouse extends Animal {

public void pinStick(){
    System.out.print("Squeak!");

}
```

}

```
public class Monkey extends Animal {

public void pinStick(){
    System.out.print("OoOoOoAhAhAh!");
}
```

}

```
public class Lion extends Animal {


public void pinStick(){
    System.out.print("Roar!");


}
```

}

Comment: is your question how to randomly add a `Monkey` to your Zoo?

Comment: No, it's how to include the Monkey classes "ooahah" when either of these two: But I have to have it print an instance of the monkey class each time the loop runs

if (r == 0) {
            animals[i] = new Mouse();


        } else{
            animals[i] = new Lion();

        }

are printed...

Comment: Like this: 
Squeak!OoOoOoAhAhAh!Squeak!OoOoOoAhAhAh!Roar!OoOoOoAhAhAh!Squeak!OoOoOoAhAhAh!Squeak!OoOoOoAhAhAh!Roar!OoOoOoAhAhAh!Squeak!OoOoOoAhAhAh!Squeak!OoOoOoAhAhAh!Roar!OoOoOoAhAhAh!Squeak!OoOoOoAhAhAh!

Comment: Yeah, that's it, it's just a task on arrays and polymorphism, including the monkey with the roar and squeak output has proved tricky for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The aim is add a new instance of the monkey class so that in the result printout you have “OoOoAhAh” together with “Squeak” and “Roar”

You can just declare another array for Monkey

```
private Animal[] monkeys;
```

constructor

```
monkeys = new Monkey[10];
```

and pushes new Monkey object in for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    r = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
    if (r == 0) {
        animals[i] = new Mouse();


    } else{
        animals[i] = new Lion();

    }

        monkeys[i] = new Monkey();

   }
```

then later on in the for loop just do the printing job

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    animals[i].pinStick();
    monkeys[i].pinStick();
}
```

Comment: No. The `Monkey` will replace the `Mouse` or `Lion` that was just added and you will end up with a zoo full of `Monkey`s.

Comment: why does it replace mouse or lion? it is allocated in separate array object (Animals and Monkeys), i've tested it.

Comment: My mistake: I didn't catch that you were using a separate `monkeys` array.